# Incomplete SOAP response

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, sudzc

I'm working with a WDSL translated with SUDZ to Objective-C, one of the methods returns a XML with parameters to call a service. The problem is that it isn't working as expected because of the translation of SudzC and I'm looking some kind of solution (I have been writing emails for almost 2 months and SudzC don't answer)

My idea is: How can I get the COMPLETE soap answer to parse it later? It could be enough.

Because the problem is that it is only taking the first parameter. If I call the method this is the answer of the handler:

[image: handler]

But then in the answer ('value') there is nothing like 'NextParameter'. Indeed, If I use 'objectAtIndex', 'allKeys'.. it throw me an exception.

[image]

This is the method:

[image: Method]

The WSDL is working, I have tried with the original in Java and here it is a little fragment of the answer:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dCcOrYg.png]

Comment: I can't help you on the broader question (I'm not familiar with your particular `SoapRequest` class, nor how it's parsing the parameters, sending the request, etc.), but your `deserializeTo` parameter is `[ParameterData alloc]`, but that should probably be `[[ParameterData alloc] init]`. And your comment says it returns a `ParameterData`, but you're obviously returning the `SoapRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

I used Sudzc + XMLDictionary (https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) class, to convert the SOAP xml to a dictionary.

Create a new request and set the delegate like this:

```
[[super soapService] products:self
                      parameter1:@"1"];

#pragma mark - SoapDelegate

- (void)onload:(id)value {
    NSDictionary *soapDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:value];

    NSDictionary *bodyDictionary = [soapDictionary objectForKey:@"soapenv:Body"];


// here you can parse the SOAP response
    NSDictionary *productsDictionary = [[bodyDictionary objectForKey:@"ns1:prductsresponse"] objectForKey:@"products"];

}
```

Comment: At first thanks for the answer but It isn't clear for me. I'm really noob on this so if you could be more explicative... I have to call the method 'getParameters' and then send the 'value' parameter to your 'onload' method? What about the firsts lines: [[Super soapService]..? Thanks again.

Comment: I see. You can ignore the [super soapService] it's just something that I copy from my project. You need to create a new variable from your service provided by Sudzc, for example Service *service = [Service alloc] init]; than you can call the soap method that you need and set the soap delegate as self [service getParameters]. Than you need to implement the SoapDelegate. The value variable of the SoapDelegate onload: method will be the SOAP response of your request, I used the XMLDictionary class to make easier the parse process. I hope this help you.

Comment: I have tried to do it anyways but still not working. My problem is that I haven't the SOAP response, indeed I have a 'ParameterData'. I dont know why. How could I get the RAW SOAP response? Thank you so much.

http://i.imgur.com/I5gbvR4.png
http://i.imgur.com/zzbZ4yl.png